# Exception when downloading outlook messages using Microsoft.Graph Client

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, office365

When trying to load the messages of an outlook mailbox using the Microsoft.Graph client library (Version 3.6.0), the following Exception is thrown:

```
System.ArgumentException: The value 'Microsoft.Graph.OutlookItem' is not of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Message' and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parametername: value

Stack Trace:
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionWrapper`1.VerifyValueType(Object value)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionWrapper`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Populate(JsonReader reader, Object target)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.CustomCreationConverter`1.ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.DeserializeConvertable(JsonConverter converter, JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   bei Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   bei Microsoft.Graph.Serializer.DeserializeObject[T](String inputString)
   bei Microsoft.Graph.ResponseHandler.<HandleResponse>d__2`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.<SendAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext()
--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---
   bei System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   bei Microsoft.Graph.MailFolderMessagesCollectionRequest.<GetAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
```

Code which fetches the messages:

```
var currentFolder = graphClient.Me.MailFolders[folderId];

var items = await currentFolder.Messages
  .Request()
  .Filter($"ReceivedDateTime ge {fromDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")} and ReceivedDateTime lt {toDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("o")}")
  .OrderBy("ReceivedDateTime DESC")
  .GetAsync();
```

This generally works, but as we can see from the exception, not always. It's not intermittent though - after occurring the first time in a mailbox, it is reproducible. Maybe the server returns some item not supported by the client library?

Unfortunately, I do not have access to the mailbox, so I cannot debug this.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: (1) I see that you're trying to get the messages from current folder. How much items it  has? If it has more contents, then it might be causing the issue here. In such scenario, i would suggest you to use  pagination ($top) and that's the best practice. (2) Just to isolate the issue you can try making the same API call with Microsoft Graph Explorer to see if you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: (1) Each request returns an Microsoft.Graph.MailFolderMessagesCollectionPage. It's CurrentPage property is an IList<Microsoft.Graph.Message>, which has only 10 items. So, pagination is done internally. To fetch subsequent pages, the application calls NextPageRequest.GetAsync(). 
(2) To do that I'd need access to the mailbox which I don't have, because it is a customer's mailbox.

Comment: Does the folder contains any other outlook items as well (say, calendar, tasks, contacts)? Not sure they're causing the issue here. It's worth to give a check or add a check at your code to see only you process the messages only.

Comment: It is not expected to see OutlookItem returned here. It is an abstract base type. It sounds like some new type is in the message folder. If I look at the beta library, it appears that there are a couple of new types that are not yet in the v1.0 schema but are in the beta schema. I wonder whether they are being exposed in the v1.0 API.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/Note.cs
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Graph/Generated/model/OutlookTask.cs